# Python selenium a button can't be clicked

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new for python selenium. I have been working for a script and I cannot press save gift options button. I used every ways(xpath css) but I couldn't. what should I do to press this button?

Snapshot of the button:

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0):

sometime x-path does not work. In my case every time buttons does not work when i find using x-path. You have to find button with it's ID and then apply click function.